# Running surefire tests in parent project

Tags: maven, surefire

I have a Maven aggregator project like this:

`/pom.xml
/module-A/pom.xml`

where in the /pom.xml, there is a

`<modules>
    <module>
        submodules/functional
    </module>
</modules>`

In the parent project, I also have many classes and tests written. They properly packaged in to the artifact. However, when I run `mvn test` only the child module's tests are executed.

To be more specific. We are managing child modules using git submodule and it does not have any dependency on the parent module. I do not know any other way to refer to the submodules without involving a Maven repository.

I tried many ways to run them and none of them works. Is there a way to test source code in the parent module?

Comment: A [Maven aggregator project](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) has to be of type `<packaging>pom`. How do you think that Maven is supposed to to execute "many classes and tests written" there? An aggregator project isn't necessarily a parent project of its modules. Are you mixing terms here? Parent/child refer to inheritance, not to aggregation. What do you exactly mean by "to refer to the submodules"? Refer from where and why?

Comment: See also [Maven: The Complete Reference, 3.6.2. Multi-module vs. Inheritance](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit).